# In react, what is the difference between calling functions with and without parentheses?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was just writing a piece of code that updates a parent component's state. This piece of code:

```
handlePress() {
    this.props.count();
    this.setState({completed: true});
};
```

managed to update the parent's state, where as this one

```
handlePress() {
    this.props.count;
    this.setState({completed: true});
};
```

did not. Therefore, what is the difference between calling functions with and without parentheses?

Comment: The way you are calling it here is unrelated to how it's used in React.  You've got a function call and a (probably) nil attribute.

Comment: If you don't have the parentheses then you haven't *called* the function at all. (Not a syntax error for the same reason that putting, say, `"test";` on a line by itself isn't a syntax error either, but just because something is syntactically valid doesn't mean it will do what you want.)

Comment: add `count` defination from parent  coomponent

Answer (score 0):

All you've done is referenced the function that you've passed in as a prop, you haven't attempted to execute it. What you've done is no different than if you had done this:

```
let count = 6;
count
```

That second line would be useless, as is when you simply use `this.props.count` instead of actually calling the function with `this.props.count()`